# Can't locate package (gimp) in terminal, and in the software center says 'not found'

Tags: software-center, software-installation, downloads, gimp

I desperately need to install Gimp on my computer. When I enter the Ubuntu Software Center Gimp is easily searchable, but when I click on it to download it says: "Not Found: there isn't a software package called 'gimp' in your current software sources". I've tried to add the program through the terminal using 
`sudo apt- get install gimp` 
to which I get the response 
`E: unable to locate package gimp` 
I've tried updates and changing my software settings, but nothing has helped and I can't find a clear fix here. 
If you have some advice, please share. 
Thanks!

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?  Also try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then try to install.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install other packages? What country are you residing (I mean, set during installation?) May be you have broken regional mirror? open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. It will be full of lines like

deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

Change the regional code to some nearby country and run `sudo apt-get update`